# How can I dynamically remove columns in a Bootstrap grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web page with Bootstrap 3. In this web page, I have a `row`. In that row, I always want to show three items. However, I really have 10 items.

When a user clicks the "remove" button, I want to remove an item, and make the next one slide in. However, I have been unable to figure out how to do this within the context of a Bootstrap `row`. Currently, my items are laid out like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div id="panel1" class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#43258A; color:#fff;">Item #1</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Item #1 Details
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div id="panel2" class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#249B73;">Item #2</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Item #2 Details
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div id="panel3" class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#FFF635;">Item #3</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Item #3 Details
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div id="panel4" class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#FE6E18;">Item #4</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Item #4 Details
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div id="panel5" class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#F91721;">Item #5</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Item #5 Details
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div id="panel6" class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#1BA8CE;">Item #6</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Item #6 Details
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div id="panel7" class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#9B3B24; color:#fff;">Item #7</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Item #7 Details
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div id="panel8" class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#0A4E38; color:#fff;">Item #8</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Item #8 Details
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div id="panel9" class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#7BE7C3;">Item #9</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Item #9 Details
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div id="panel10" class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#E7B22A;">Item #10</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Item #10 Details
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="removeFirst()">
    Remove This
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="removeSecond()">
    Remove This
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="removeThird()">
    Remove This
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

To manage the state of the items, I have the following JavaScript:

```
var visiblePanels = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function removeFirst() {
  var panelId = '#panel' + visiblePanels[0];
  $(panelId).fadeOut({
    duration:500
  });
  visiblePanels.splice(0, 1);
}

function removeSecond() {
  var panelId = '#panel' + visiblePanels[1];
  $(panelId).fadeOut({
    duration:500
  });
  visiblePanels.splice(1, 1);
}

function removeThird() {
  var panelId = '#panel' + visiblePanels[2];
  $(panelId).fadeOut({
    duration:500
  });
  visiblePanels.splice(2, 1);
}
```

The problem is, I can't get the items to slide to the left when an item is removed. In addition, the items wrap instead of just being hidden beyond the first row. I've created a Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/humotrj0/78/) to show the code running.

Answer (score 1):

Add the parent() method to hide the whole Bootstrap column

```
$(panelId).parent().fadeOut({
   duration:500
});
```

[**Demo 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/humotrj0/79/)

To get the extra pseudo-rows of items to be hidden, you'll probably have to set a max-height and hide overflow on the parent row:

```
.row.some-class {
    max-height: 110px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/humotrj0/81)

The drawback here is that you'd have to have items that never change height, and you'll have to use media queries to account for cases where heights change due to text wrapping, etc. You might be better off using one of the many jQuery sliders instead.

Comment: Sorry I stomped all over your answer. :) Edit as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fadeOut a parent() as mantioned in the other answer. Also you need to add one more wrapping `<div class="frm">` for horizontal scrolling of aligned boxes. This div dedicated to being as wide as set of boxes aligned horisontally. I repalced fadeOut with hide - it looks much better. 
there are additional css attributes for `.row`:

```
.row {
  overflow:hidden;
  height: auto;
}
```

Here is  snippet

```js
var visiblePanels = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
$(".frm").width($(".row").width()*visiblePanels.length/2.5);
$(".frm > div").width($(".row").width()/3.4);
$(window).resize(function(){
$(".frm > div").width($(".row").width()/3.4);});

function removeFirst() {
  var panelId = '#panel' + visiblePanels[0];
  $(panelId).parent().hide({
    duration:500
  });
  visiblePanels.splice(0, 1);

}

function removeSecond() {
  var panelId = '#panel' + visiblePanels[1];
  $(panelId).parent().hide({
    duration:500
  });
  visiblePanels.splice(1,1);
}

function removeThird() {
  var panelId = '#panel' + visiblePanels[2];
  $(panelId).parent().hide({
    duration:500
  });
  visiblePanels.splice(2,1);
}
```

```css
.row {
  overflow:hidden;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<div class="frm">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div id="panel1" class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#43258A; color:#fff;">Item #1</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Item #1 Details 
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div id="panel2" class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#249B73;">Item #2</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Item #2 Details
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div id="panel3" class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#FFF635;">Item #3</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Item #3 Details
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div id="panel4" class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#FE6E18;">Item #4</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Item #4 Details
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div id="panel5" class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#F91721;">Item #5</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Item #5 Details
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div id="panel6" class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#1BA8CE;">Item #6</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Item #6 Details
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div id="panel7" class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#9B3B24; color:#fff;">Item #7</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Item #7 Details
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div id="panel8" class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#0A4E38; color:#fff;">Item #8</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Item #8 Details
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div id="panel9" class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#7BE7C3;">Item #9</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Item #9 Details
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div id="panel10" class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#E7B22A;">Item #10</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Item #10 Details
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
  </div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="removeFirst()">
    Remove This
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="removeSecond()">
    Remove This
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="removeThird()">
    Remove This
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's going on with the `.frm` element? You should probably mention that tidbit in your answer, as it seems to be a critical component of the solution.